# The application is not installed on iPhone it requires newer version of iPhone os

Tags: iphone

HI...i have the Xcodes of 3.1.3 and 3.2.2 and 4.0 on my mac. i developed an application with project format - Xcode 3.1 compatible... my device's OS is 3.1.2 its .. when i tried to install the app, iTunes is showing the above message. please tell me where would be the problem.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set the iPhone OS Deployment Target to iPhone 3.0  in project settings

its worked fine..

Thank u